# Does bankruptcy remove all buildings based on when their construction started or finished?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

So my economic policy has proved a bit unsustainable, and I'm now several thousand gold in debt. I plan to declare bankruptcy, but I figure there's no reason to rush into things. I would like to capitalize on my credit as much as possible, so I took out several thousands more in loans and built a bunch of buildings.

I know that buildings built or upgraded in the the last five years get undone, but when does this start counting from? For instance, my manufactory took five years to build. Can I safely declare bankruptcy as soon as it's finished or do I have to wait another five for a total of ten?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You'll have to wait another 5 years once the manufactory is complete.**

Bankruptcy kills off all buildings being constructed/upgraded or have been constructed/upgraded in the last 5 years as you mentioned in your post.

Source: 1k+ hours of EU4